# ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis when assigning new column to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to figure out what hours in my datetime index are between 2 different hours.

This is my code:

```
rbe60['result'] = rbe60.index.hour.to_series().between(3,23)
```

The only problem is I keep getting this error.

```
    raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

I've looked at some other posts and realize it means that I probably have a duplicate value somewhere either in my index or the columns. I've tried to run to see where the duplicates would be but both come up empty.

```
dup = rbe60.index.get_duplicates() and 
dup = rbe60.columns.get_duplicates()
```

Is there anything else i should be trying?

A little more on what I'm trying to do:

Here is my data and I'm simply trying to add a condition to a np.logical statement which checks that the hour of my dataframe index is betwen 3 and 23.

```
                       Open       H       L       C       O
DateTime                                                   
2013-12-30 14:30:00 -0.0756 -0.0729 -0.0756 -0.0737  2.8847
2013-12-30 15:30:00 -0.0735  -0.072 -0.0737 -0.0722  2.8870
2013-12-30 16:30:00 -0.0722 -0.0721 -0.0728 -0.0722  2.8930
2013-12-30 18:00:00 -0.0728 -0.0728 -0.0728 -0.0728  2.8826
2013-12-30 19:00:00 -0.0721 -0.0721 -0.0721 -0.0721  2.8872
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with _some_ data, at least.

Comment: Or, perhaps all you needed to do was circumvent index allignment: `rbe60['result'] = rbe60.index.hour.to_series().between(3,23).values`

Comment: @coldspeed made the edits and provided the data. It looks like using .values does the trick. For my own edification, any ideas as to why I was getting that error in the first place after checking for duplicates on both axes?

Comment: Hopefully, the answer clarifies it.

Comment: It does. Very well - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is index alignment. Your DataFrame consists of an index of `datetime`s. Your existing code returns something that looks like:

```
print(rbe60.index.hour.to_series().between(3,23))
DateTime
14    True
15    True
16    True
18    True
19    True
Name: DateTime, dtype: bool
```

Notice that the index values do not match up with that of the original. This throws pandas off during assignment. The solution is to assign an array, that isn't associated with an index at all.

```
print(rbe60.index.hour.to_series().between(3,23).values)
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

IOW,

```
rbe60['result'] = rbe60.index.hour.to_series().between(3,23).values
```